# running php3 localhost

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, localhost

I have this project that i HAVE to work on, have been working on for a few years. It was coded with php3 and at first, i couldn't get it to work on my localhost (XAMPP) cos it had php5 installed.

However, i was somehow able to get it to work, just the way godaddy and other hosts get the same php3 files to work on their servers. Now, my computer crashed and i have to install a new XAMPP and i can't get my old web files to work anymore.

I also have a problem with a Joomla website which is now also not working on my XAMPP anymore.

Does anyone have any idea WHY???

Comment: there are 2 websites i'm having problems with:

1. A php3 website, it's not even showing anything at all... nothing!
2. a joomla website that requires php5. that one now gives **Error 500**

That's it. I remember that i had to tweak my php.ini file to allow the php3 files to work, but i don't remember how i did it.

I know that a hosting company like godaddy.com will add an extra php.ini file to the root directory, but even with that on my local host, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Take a look at the [PHP release history page](http://php.net/releases/index.php). Note when PHP3 was superseded by PHP4: May 2000. PHP has changed beyond recognition since then. Code that was written for PHP3 is unlikely to work properly (if at all) in PHP5. And if you do get it working, it will be dangerously insecure, because web site security was not even thought of back in 2000. My advice: throw away the old php3 code and start a fresh project. Odds are it'll be less work that way anyway.

Comment: sure, that's an option... but for the far future! they have started using the system and i managed to make it stable BEFORE my computer crashed. it works online, but no longer on my localhost. i just don't remember how i did it the first time.

Comment: found the solution... same solution i used years ago lol
**SOLUTION**
Set the following parameters in your php.ini file:

register_globals = on
register_long_arrays = on
expose_php = off
variables_order = "EGPCS"

Comment: You should seriously talk to whoever is in charge and tell them just how bad it is to have PHP3 code around! It's code from the era when Y2K was a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution... Same solution I used years ago. Set the following parameters in your `php.ini` file:

```
register_globals = on
register_long_arrays = on
expose_php = off
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```